# Why is the value of index always zero when "variable_names" returns multiple results?

Tags: python, for-loop, enumerate

I want to count the results in each regex search against a file. I believe I'm populating a list and then looping through trying to get the value of a counter.

```
for file in XDTS:
    data_tag_regex = re.compile(r'data_tag=\"(.*?)\"')
    if file.endswith('.xdt'):
        xdt_file = open(file, 'r')
        for line in xdt_file:
            variable_names = data_tag_regex.findall(line)
            for index, variable_name in enumerate(variable_names):
                print(index)
```

Comment: Could you provide whatever else is necessary to test this code?  Sample data, for example, that is generating the problem described?

Comment: can you add a sample line of to apply this regex?, which output would you expect from than sample line?

Comment: you might want to include some sample data...

Comment: You don't need to escape `"` inside a regular expression.

Comment: Is it maybe possible that the last for always iterates through a 1-length variable_names value? i.e. the first two for loops may have multiple values to iterate through, but the last one always has only a single value (and thus results in an index of 0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one match *per line*, and multiple lines match. Your `enumerate()` call is starting from 0 each time because it is a *new call* for each new line:

```
for line in xdt_file:
    # per line, find matches
    variable_names = data_tag_regex.findall(line)
    # for *this line only* print the indices, counting from 0
    for index, variable_name in enumerate(variable_names):
        print(index)
```

If you wanted to keep an index *per match across all lines*, you need to count independently:

```
index = 0
for line in xdt_file:
    variable_names = data_tag_regex.findall(line)
    for variable_name in variable_names:
        index += 1
        print(index)
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. I was thinking I was getting all matches, not per line and came back to remove the question but it seems Stack Overflow is amazing quick ...

Comment: Would it cleaner or faster or better in any other way to read all the lines at once, then run the regex?

Comment: @MattRalston: Not from a memory point of view. Given a reasonably sized file, I'd parse it line by line.